# Динамический прогресс бар с датой и наложением цвета на дату

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, pixijs

Задача сделать динамический progress bar.

Во первых должно изменяться время, которое осталось до определённой даты. С этим проблем нет.
Основной вопрос - как сделать так, чтобы цифры заливались по контуру? (этот контур тоже считается динамически от остaвшегося).

Нужен совет в какую сторону вообще смотреть, ибо у меня в голове не совсем понятно как это реализовать. В теории должно быть какое-то перекрытие между 2 текстурами - текстом и белым прямоугольником. Но ничего похожего я не нашёл.
Интересует подход к решению на чистом canvas или three.js или pixi.js. Спасибо!

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Чисто из любопытства: зачем three.js нужен для этого?

Comment: Видимо у меня three.js головного мозга)

Comment: Не, ну, пара вариантов того, как это можно организовать в three.js, конечно же есть :) Но использование CSS мне как-то кажется более подходящим для достижения желаемого результата.

Comment: Ну на самом деле CSS поддержка не такая уж и хорошая.  https://caniuse.com/#search=background-clip%3Atext. Весь IE в пролёте. Так что я склоняюсь в сторону canvas. Может есть идеи как сделать не на CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Голый canvas с отрисовкой:

```js
var text = "6D:20:50:17";
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "bold 96px Times New Roman";
ctx.textAlign = 'center';

function drawText() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 512, 128);
  ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, Math.floor(Math.random() * 512), 128);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
  ctx.fillText(text, 256, 96);

  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";

  ctx.strokeStyle = "maroon";
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.strokeText(text, 256, 96);
}

drawText();

setInterval(drawText, 1000);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="512" height="128"></canvas>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это именно то, что я искал.

Comment: @AlexeyKapustsin Пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 1):

Вариант на чистом css:

```css
body{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: black;
}

h1 {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, tomato 17%,  transparent 17%);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #ffffff
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Text Transparent</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: На самом деле неплохой вариант, но не совсем то что я бы хотел видеть. Из плохого - поддержка.

Answer (score 0):

Регулируется с помощью `background-position` от `0%` до `-100%`... Но к сожалению работает только в webkit-браузерах. Для остальных браузеров можно сделать fallback.

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, yellow 0%, green 100%);
}

h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-size: 70px;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, red 50%);
  background-size: 200% 200%;
  background-position: -43% center;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Character</h1>
</div>
```